# Removing array of elements for a certain array

Tags: php, arrays

So i have 3 arrays that look like this:

```
$store = array("store_number"=>"1", "store_number"=>"2", "store_number"=>"3" ,"store_number"=>"4" ,"store_number"=>"5", "store_number"=>"6");

$caffe = array("store_number"=>"3" ,"store_number"=>"4");

$fastfood = array("store_number"=>"5" ,"store_number"=>"6");
```

What it want is to remove elements that exist in $fastfood and $caffe from the array $store, which should look like this

```
$store = array("store_number"=>"1", "store_number"=>"2")
```

So basically i just want to remove elements that already exist in $fastfood and $caffe from array $store
Anyone have an idea how could i do this? I'm doing this in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$store = array_diff(array_diff($store, $fastfood), $caffe);
```